# My command line code doesn't run using cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line, cmd, shell-exec

My problem is that I cannot run cURL in PHP on the command line. My code is like this:

```
public function updateSolrProfilData($arrData)
{
  $solrClientOptionsCommit = $this->solrClientOptionsYazProfilCommit;

  $urlCommit = "http://" . $solrClientOptionsCommit['hostname'] . ":" . $solrClientOptionsCommit['port'] . "/" . $solrClientOptionsCommit['path'] . "/update?stream.body=%3Ccommit/%3E -H \"Content-Type: text/xml\" --data-binary '<add><doc>";

  foreach ($arrData as $firmaField => $firmaValue)
  {
    if ( ! is_array($firmaValue))
    {
      $urlCommit = $urlCommit . '<field name="' . $firmaField . '">' . $firmaValue . '</field>';
    }
    else
    {
      foreach ($firmaValue as $firmaField2 => $firmaValue2)
      {
        if ('' != $firmaValue2)
        {
          $urlCommit = $urlCommit . '<field name="' . $firmaField . '">' . $firmaValue2 . "</field>";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $urlCommit .= "</doc></add>'";

  $urlCommit = htmlspecialchars($urlCommit);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlCommit);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

When I run it on the command line, it works, but it doesn't work when using cURL nor the PHP shell_exec function. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Could you post the exact command that should work in console? As well as what this command call produces

Comment: And, I've almost forgot, what OS do you use?

Comment: How it doesn't work? Is there any error or just failing ?

Comment: latest ubuntu edition. I post the exact command and it works in terminal. And it gives me the following as result:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">557</int></lst>
</response>

Comment: By the way working command is this:
curl http://IP_ADDRESS:8986/solr/collection1/update?stream.body=%3Ccommit/%3E -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="id">www.inform.com.tr</field><field name="site">test</field><field name="url_Domain">test</field><field name="url_Page">test</field><field name="url_Profil">test</field><field name="scr_Kobi_Rank">666</field></doc></add>'

Comment: The problem is that gives me no error. Neither shell_exec nor curl

Comment: add ini_set("display_errors", "On") and error_reporting( E_ALL) at begining of the code to see the errors

Comment: `working command is this`, so? What is the problem then? Yet again, post the EXACT command, - I don't think anybody can answer tour question before you do so.

Comment: I changed error configuration and still gives no errors.

Comment: And yes it is working command without IP Address. Do you really need IP?

Comment: Ok I found the solution. It was because of htmlspecialchars. I removed it and now it works.

Comment: @OnurGöker - when you get a chance (and permissions from StackOverflow), please add your solution as an answer and accept it. That way, this one won't show up in the "unanswered" queries anymore. Thanks and welcome to SO!